# replacing a string with an HTML element

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string that I want to replace the 'xx' with a line break. I am writing this in a jsp page, just fyi. So for instance:

```
tmpString1 = "hello, how are youxxnice to meet you"
string1 = tmpString1.replace('xx', '<br />');
```

That explains what I would like to do. but I get an unclosed character literal error on this attempt, I have also tried:

```
tmpString1 = "hello, how are youxxnice to meet you"
string1 = tmpString1.replace('xx', '/n');
```

And this way it just replaces the 'xx' with a space, I know this seems trivial, but I cant seem to get it working.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be -

```
tmpString1 = "hello, how are youxxnice to meet you";
string1 = tmpString1.replace("xx", "<br />");
```

Note the double quotes for parameters in `replace` method, as these is not character but String

Comment: can .replace work with strings rather than chars?  Because I am getting a different error using that

Comment: it should work.. if your code is exact same as you pasted then you missed semicolon in first line - the assignment of the tmpString1  veriable

Comment: replace also should work for your example also replaceAll takes regex, probably that will give you more fine control

Answer (score 2):

Use double-quotes for strings. Single-quotes are for chars.

```
string1 = tmpString1.replace("xx", "<br />");
```